# Java SSLSocket stop handshake after sometime

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

i am in a strange problem and i can't seem to find the reason for why this is happening. The SSL Socket in the app works fine when the app gets started at first, but after sometime or after some load the handshake process starts to have issues. when tested through openssl command, it sometimes get stuck for some seconds after write client hello and then return no certificate available error, or sometimes it give this error

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:unknown state
```

Here is the code for how the SSLSocket is created and keystore initialized.

**Class Start**

```
public synchronized void start(CamdMessageListener listener, CaProfile profile) throws IOException, SocketException {
    this.profile = profile;
    if (srv == null) {
        try {
           createServerSocket();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
    if (acceptThread == null && null != srv) {
        if (useSsl) {
            acceptThread = new AcceptSSLThread(listener, this);
        }
        else {
            acceptThread = new AcceptThread(listener, this);
        }
    }
    portNumbers.put(new Integer(port), this);
    acceptThread.start();
    alive = true;
}
```

**Create Server Socket**

```
public void createServerSocket() throws IOException {
    synchronized (this) {
        if (this.useSsl) {
            ListenPort.logger.info("(ListenPort " + this.port + ") creating SSL server Socket , using Ssl : On");
            try {
                final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
                ListenPort.logger.info("ListenPort " + this.port + ") Default keymanagerFactory algorithm:  '" + KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm() + "'.");
                //final KeyManagerList keyManagers = new KeyManagerList();
                //final TrustManagerList trustManagers = new TrustManagerList();
                final ArrayList<KeyManager> keyManagers = new ArrayList<KeyManager>();
                final ArrayList<TrustManager> trustManagers = new ArrayList<TrustManager>();

                this.keystores.forEach((k, v) -> {
                    try {
                        ListenPort.logger.info("(ListenPort " + this.port + ") ssl On : keystore ='" + k + "'");
                        final KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
                        final KeyStore ks2 = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
                        final FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(k);
                        ListenPort.logger.info("(ListenPort " + this.port + ") Retrieving ssl ids from keystore '" + k + "' = passwd '" + v + "'");
                        ks2.load(fis, v.toCharArray());
                        ListenPort.logger.info("(ListenPort " + this.port + ")                         keystore '" + k + "' Loaded.");
                        final KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
                        final TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
                        ListenPort.logger.info("(ListenPort " + this.port + ")          initializing Keymanager '" + k + "'.");
                        kmf.init(ks2, v.toCharArray());
                        final KeyManager[] km = kmf.getKeyManagers();
                        if (km.length > 0) {
                            ListenPort.logger.finest("(ListenPort " + this.port + ") Reading " + km.length + " key(s)");
                            for (int i = 0; i < km.length; ++i) {
                                ListenPort.logger.finest("(ListenPort " + this.port + ") Reading key " + km[i]);
                                keyManagers.add(km[i]);
                            }
                        }
                        ListenPort.logger.info("(ListenPort " + this.port + ")          initializing trustmanager '" + k + "'.");
                        tmf.init(ks2);
                        final TrustManager[] tm = tmf.getTrustManagers();
                        if (tm.length > 0) {
                            ListenPort.logger.finest("(ListenPort " + this.port + ") Reading " + km.length + " trust(s)");
                            for (int j = 0; j < tm.length; ++j) {
                                ListenPort.logger.finest("(ListenPort " + this.port + ")  Reading trust " + tm[j]);
                                trustManagers.add(tm[j]);
                            }
                        }
                        ListenPort.logger.info("(ListenPort " + this.port + ") Retrieving ssl On : from keystore '" + k + "' ok");
                    }
                    catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e7) {
                        ListenPort.logger.info("(ListenPort " + this.port + ") ssl On : keystore ='" + k + "' unrecoverable Key");
                    }
                    catch (KeyStoreException e8) {
                        ListenPort.logger.info("(ListenPort " + this.port + ") ssl On : keystore ='" + k + "' Bad Keystore");
                    }
                    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e9) {
                        ListenPort.logger.info("(ListenPort " + this.port + ") ssl On : keystore ='" + k + "' No such Algorithm");
                    }
                    catch (CertificateException e10) {
                        ListenPort.logger.info("(ListenPort " + this.port + ") ssl On : keystore ='" + k + "' Bad Certificate");
                    }
                    catch (IOException e11) {
                        ListenPort.logger.severe("(ListenPort " + this.port + ") ssl On : keystore ='" + k + "' IOExcept");
                    }
                    return;
                });
                try {
                    KeyManager[] km2 = new KeyManager[0];
                    TrustManager[] tp = new TrustManager[0];
                    km2 = keyManagers.toArray(km2);
                    tp = trustManagers.toArray(tp);
                    ListenPort.logger.finest("(ListenPort " + this.port + ") Init SSL Context : " + km2.length + " key , " + tp.length + " trusts");
                    sslContext.init(km2, tp, null);
                    SSLServerSocket sslsrv;
                    if (this.bindAddr == null) {
                        ListenPort.logger.finest("(ListenPort " + this.port + ") No specific Binding Address");
                        sslsrv = (SSLServerSocket)sslContext.getServerSocketFactory().createServerSocket(this.port);
                    }
                    else {
                        ListenPort.logger.finest("(ListenPort " + this.port + ") Binding Address" + this.bindAddr.getHostAddress());
                        sslsrv = (SSLServerSocket)sslContext.getServerSocketFactory().createServerSocket(this.port, 0, this.bindAddr);
                    }
                    ListenPort.logger.finest("(ListenPort " + this.port + ") Enabling protocols");
                    String[] protocols = sslsrv.getSupportedProtocols();
                    for (int l = 0; l < protocols.length; ++l) {
                        ListenPort.logger.finest("(ListenPort " + this.port + ")                 " + protocols[l]);
                    }
                    sslsrv.setEnabledProtocols(protocols);
                    String[] suites = sslsrv.getSupportedCipherSuites();
                    ListenPort.logger.finest("(ListenPort " + this.port + ") Supported cipher suites are:");
                    for (int m = 0; m < suites.length; ++m) {
                        ListenPort.logger.finest("(ListenPort " + this.port + ")            " + suites[m]);
                    }
                    sslsrv.setEnabledCipherSuites(suites);
                    suites = sslsrv.getEnabledCipherSuites();
                    ListenPort.logger.finest("(ListenPort " + this.port + ") Supported cipher suites are:");
                    for (int m = 0; m < suites.length; ++m) {
                        ListenPort.logger.finest("(ListenPort " + this.port + ")            " + suites[m]);
                    }
                    ListenPort.logger.finest("(ListenPort " + this.port + ") Support protocols are:");
                    protocols = sslsrv.getSupportedProtocols();
                    for (int m = 0; m < protocols.length; ++m) {
                        ListenPort.logger.finest("(ListenPort " + this.port + ")            " + protocols[m]);
                    }
                    this.srv = sslsrv;
                }
                catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    ListenPort.logger.warning("ListenPort " + this.port + ") Erreur Creating server socket : " + e.getMessage());
                }
                catch (IOException e2) {
                    ListenPort.logger.warning("ListenPort " + this.port + ") Erreur Creating server socket" + e2.getMessage());
                }
                ListenPort.logger.info("(ListenPort " + this.port + ") ssl On server created");
            }
            catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e3) {
                if (null != this.srv) {
                    this.srv.close();
                }
                this.srv = null;
                System.err.println(" open ssl listenning port : no such algorithm");
                ListenPort.logger.severe("ListenPort " + this.port + ") open ssl listenning port : no such algorithm disabling ssl : " + e3.getMessage());
            }
            catch (KeyManagementException e4) {
                if (null != this.srv) {
                    this.srv.close();
                }
                this.srv = null;
                ListenPort.logger.severe("(ListenPort " + this.port + ") creating SSL server Socket :key management problem " + e4.getMessage());
            }
            catch (Exception e5) {
                if (null != this.srv) {
                    this.srv.close();
                }
                this.srv = null;
                ListenPort.logger.info("(ListenPort " + this.port + ") creating SSL server Socket :key  management problem " + e5.getMessage());
            }
            ListenPort.logger.info("(ListenPort " + this.port + ") creating server Socket , using Ssl : On");
        }
        else {
            srv = new ServerSocket();
            try {
                if (this.bindAddr == null) {
                    srv.bind(new InetSocketAddress(this.port));
                }
                else {
                    srv.bind(new InetSocketAddress(this.bindAddr, this.port));
                }
            }
            catch (BindException e6) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**AcceptSSLThread**

```
public void run()
{
    while (this.listenPort.isAlive()) {
      try
      {
        SSLSocket s = (SSLSocket)this.listenPort.getServerSocket().accept();

        SSLSession sess = s.getSession();
        this.logger.info("Peer host is " + sess.getPeerHost());
        this.logger.info("Cipher is " + sess.getCipherSuite());
        this.logger.info("Protocol is " + sess.getProtocol());
        this.logger.info("ID is " + sess.getId());
        this.logger.info("Session created in " + sess.getCreationTime());
        this.logger.info("Session accessed in " + sess.getLastAccessedTime());


        String ip = s.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();

        int maxThreads = ProxyConfig.getInstance().getMaxThreads();
        if (Thread.activeCount() > maxThreads) {
          try {
            Thread.sleep(1000L);
          } catch (InterruptedException localInterruptedException) {}
          this.logger.severe("Max-threads exceeded (" + maxThreads + "), closing incoming connection: " + CustomFormatter.formatAddress(ip));
          s.close();


        }
        else if ((!this.listenPort.isAllowed(ip)) || (this.listenPort.isDenied(ip))) {
          this.logger.fine("Rejected connection: " + CustomFormatter.formatAddress(ip) + " not allowed.");
          com.bowman.cardserv.session.SessionManager.getInstance().fireUserLoginFailed("?@" + ip, this.listenPort + "/", ip, "rejected by [" + this.listenPort + "] ip deny list.");
          s.close();
        } else {
          this.logger.fine("Accepted connection: " + CustomFormatter.formatAddress(ip));

          ProxySession ps;
          try
          {
            ps = createSession(s, this.listenPort, this.listener);
          } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            this.logger.fine("Unknown Host Excpeption: " + CustomFormatter.formatAddress(ip) + " : " + e.getMessage() + "' cause: " + e.getCause().getMessage());
            ps = null;
          } catch (IOException e) {
            this.logger.fine("IOExcpeption: " + CustomFormatter.formatAddress(ip) + " : " + e.getMessage() + "' cause: " + e.getCause().getMessage());
            ps = null;
          }
          catch (Exception e) {
            this.logger.fine("Exception : " + CustomFormatter.formatAddress(ip) + " : " + e.getMessage() + "' cause: " + e.getCause().getMessage());
            ps = null;
          }
          if (ps == null) {
            try { s.close();
            }
            catch (Exception localException1) {}
          }
        }
      } catch (java.net.SocketException e) {
        this.logger.throwing("Server socket closed: " + this.listenPort + " (" + e.getMessage() + ")", e);
        this.listenPort.destroy();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        this.logger.severe("Exception accepting socket connection for [" + this.listenPort + "], aborting...", e);
        this.listenPort.destroy();
      } catch (Throwable t) {
        this.logger.severe("Error in accept loop: " + t, t);
        return;
      }
    }
}
```

The issue sometimes happen after few minutes and sometimes after few hours, maybe the user load has something to do with the issue. But when starting the app it works just fine, and there is a system for refreshing the socket if the configuration file is changed, so if i change the configuration file and the SSL code is executed again then it start working again for sometime and stops again after sometime. This is really driving me crazy.

Also here is the part of code where if the config gets updated it refresh the keystore.

```
public void configUpdated(ProxyXmlConfig xml) throws ConfigException {
    int port = xml.getPortValue("listen-port");

    if (portNumbers.containsKey(new Integer(port))) {
        ListenPort lp = (ListenPort)portNumbers.get(new Integer(port));
        if (lp != this) {
            throw new ConfigException(xml.getFullName(), "listen-port", "Listen-port '" + port + "' already in use by [" + lp + "]");
        }
    }
    ProxyXmlConfig sslXml = null;
    try {
        sslXml = xml.getSubConfig("ssl");
    }
    catch (ConfigException e) {
        ListenPort.logger.info("(ListenPort " + port + ") " + e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception e2) {
        ListenPort.logger.info("(ListenPort " + port + ") " + e2.getMessage());
    }

    if (sslXml != null && "true".equalsIgnoreCase(sslXml.getStringValue("enabled"))) {
        Iterator iter = sslXml.getMultipleSubConfigs("keystore");
        this.keystores.clear();
        if (iter != null) {
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                ProxyXmlConfig keystore = (ProxyXmlConfig) iter.next();
                if (keystore.getName() != null && keystore.getName().length() > 0) {
                    String passwd = keystore.getStringValue("password");
                    String store = keystore.getContents();
                    if (new File(store).exists()) {
                        this.keystores.put(store, passwd);
                        ListenPort.logger.finest("(ListenPort " + port + ") loading from config file :'" + store + "' passwd '" + passwd + "'");
                    }
                    else {
                        ListenPort.logger.warning("(ListenPort " + port + ") +Keystore file " + keystore.getName() + "unreachable - ignoring ");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        this.useSsl = true;
    }
    setPort(port);

    String bindIp = null; bindAddr = null;
    try {
        bindIp = xml.getStringValue("bind-ip");
    } catch (ConfigException ex) {}
    if(bindIp != null) try {
      bindAddr = InetAddress.getByName(bindIp);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e3) {
    ListenPort.logger.throwing("ListenPort " + port + ") Bind IP Exception '" + e3.getMessage() + "' for bindin " + bindIp, new ConfigException(xml.getFullName(), "bind-ip", "Invalid listen-port bind-ip: " + bindIp));
    } catch (Exception e4) {
    ListenPort.logger.throwing("ListenPort " + port + ") Bind IP Exception '" + e4.getMessage() + "' for bindin " + bindIp, new ConfigException(xml.getFullName(), "bind-ip", "Invalid listen-port bind-ip: " + bindIp));
    }

    properties.clear();
    Iterator iter2 = xml.getMultipleSubConfigs(null);
    if (iter2 != null) {
        ProxyXmlConfig e5; 
        while (iter2.hasNext()) {
            e5 = (ProxyXmlConfig)iter2.next();
            if (e5.getName() != null && e5.getName().length() > 0) {
                this.properties.put(e5.getName(), xml);
            }
        }

        try {
            e5 = (ProxyXmlConfig)properties.remove("allow-list");
            if (e5 == null) throw new ConfigException("");
            String allow = e5.getStringValue("allow-list");
            allowList = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(allow.split(" ")));
        } catch (ConfigException ce) {
          allowList = new HashSet();
        }
        try {
            e5 = (ProxyXmlConfig)properties.remove("deny-list");
            if (e5 == null) throw new ConfigException("");
            String deny = e5.getStringValue("deny-list");
            denyList = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(deny.split(" ")));
        } catch (ConfigException ce) {
          denyList = new HashSet();
        }

    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: It is nonsensical to initialize both keymanagers and TrustManagers from the same keystore file, and to enable all supported protocols.

Comment: @EJP Do you think that could be the cause of the issue? I think i don't really need to initialize a truststore, just a keystore would do i think (i still don't completely understand this whole truststore and keystore difference).